# Setting minimum value to a textbox

Tags: excel, textbox, minimum, vba

I am using a userform with multiple textbox. I was wondering if there is a way of forcing the user to input a minimum value or higher before moving to the next textbox.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Look at the TextBox1_KeyDown or Keypress events. In that event you can check the value of the other textbox and bail if it has not been set.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one of your textboxes is named `TextBox1` you can place this code in your userform:

```
Option Explicit

Dim blnClosing As Boolean

Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

        If blnClosing = False Then

                Dim iVal As Integer
                Dim minVal As Integer

                minVal = 10 'Change to your needs

                'Test for numeric characters
                On Error Resume Next
                iVal = CInt(Me.TextBox1.Value)

                'If characters are not numeric
                If Err.Number = 13 Then
                        MsgBox "Value must be numeric!", vbCritical, "Incorrect Value"
                        Me.TextBox1.Text = vbNullString
                        Cancel = True 'Retain focus on the textbox
                        Exit Sub
                End If

                'Reset error handling to normal
                On Error GoTo 0

                'Check if textbox value is less than the minimum
                If Me.TextBox1.Value < minVal Then
                        MsgBox "Value must be greater than " & minVal & "", vbCritical, "Incorrect Value"
                        Me.TextBox1.Value = vbNullString
                        Cancel = True 'Retain focus on the textbox
                End If
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
        blnClosing = True
End Sub
```

I took the liberty of checking for a numeric value as well, since you are asking if the value in the textbox appears to be required to be numeric.  If that's not the case remove the lines of code from the `'Test for numeric characters` comment down to the `On ErrorGoTo 0` line.

The global variable `blnClosing` allows us to skip over the code when the form is closing.  If this wasn't included and the user pressed 'X' on the upper right hand corner of the form with invalid data (blank, less than the minimum, or non-numeric) then the messageboxes would show.